# NPM fail on Debian 9

Tags: debian, npm

I'm trying to install jquery on Debian 9 and it fails.  I have installed other packages using npm with no problem.  When I execute **npm install jquery**, I get this error: **npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/package.json'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command should work, as jquery exists in the npm registry. Why is it telling you to look in /etc ? Is your shell there for some reason? Do you have an internet connection?

If you want to install it globally, you can run (as sudo)

```
npm install -g jquery
```

but for the life of me I can’t figure out why that would make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Update `npm` then create the `package.json` file:

```
npm i -g npm
npm init
```

Install the `jquery`:

```
npm install jquery
```